# Can't connect to Microsoft SQL Server via Node

Tags: node.js, sql-server

In command prompt I can do this

`sqlcmd -S DESKTOP-7OPSCVV\SQLEXPRESS -U test -P test -d chem -Q "SELECT * FROM Questions"`

And it will show me the data from the table. This was after I enabled 1433 port, allowed TCP connection in SQL Server Configuration, and in SQL Server Manager, allowed user permissions for the chem database.

However, for my node.js code, I have

```
const express = require('express');
const sql = require('mssql');


const config = {
    server: 'DESKTOP-7OPSCVV\\SQLEXPRESS',
    database: 'chem',
    user: 'test',
    password: 'test',
    options: {
      trustServerCertificate: true // Change to 'false' if not using a trusted certificate
    }
  };
  

  const app = express();

app.get('/data', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    await sql.connect(config);
    const result = await sql.query('SELECT * FROM Questions');
    res.json(result.recordset);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.status(500).send('Error retrieving data from the database2');
  }
});
```

And get the error

```
> server@1.0.0 start
> node server.js

Server listening on port 3000
ConnectionError: Failed to connect to DESKTOP-7OPSCVV\SQLEXPRESS in 15000ms
    at D:\ochem\exam\server\node_modules\mssql\lib\tedious\connection-pool.js:85:17
    at Connection.onConnect (D:\ochem\exam\server\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:838:9)
    at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:629:26)
    at Connection.emit (node:events:514:28)
    at Connection.emit (D:\ochem\exam\server\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:959:18)
    at Connection.connectTimeout (D:\ochem\exam\server\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1209:10)
    at Timeout._onTimeout (D:\ochem\exam\server\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1154:12)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:573:17)
    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:514:7) {
  code: 'ETIMEOUT',
  originalError: ConnectionError: Failed to connect to DESKTOP-7OPSCVV\SQLEXPRESS in 15000ms
      at Connection.connectTimeout (D:\ochem\exam\server\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1209:26)
      at Timeout._onTimeout (D:\ochem\exam\server\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1154:12)
      at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:573:17)
      at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:514:7) {
    code: 'ETIMEOUT'
  }
}
```

Shouldn't the connection be allowed since I got it to work in command prompt?

Comment: The SQL Browser service is responsible for converting an instance name into the TCP port that the instance is listening on - but it only reads instance configurations as it starts up, it doesn't detect subsequent changes. Whenever you change the Server Protocols settings in SQL Server Configuration Manager do you remember to restart the SQL Browser service?

Comment: Also, since it seems that you're using Tedious behind the mssql module, have you tried specifying the instance name via `config.options.instanceName` instead of via `config.server`? Ref: [mssql # Tedious](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql#tedious)

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Yes. To be specific, in SQL Server Configuration, under SQL Server Services, I restarted the SQL Server. 
I also tried ```config.server``` but still same issue.

Comment: SQL Server != SQL Browser. If you change any of SQL Server's server protocol configurations you also need to restart the SQL Browser service so that clients trying to resolve instance names will see the new changes.

Comment: Side note: the code comment `// Change to 'false' if not using a trusted certificate` is nonsense. If the certificate is self-signed that doesn't make it "trusted". It is simply insecure to use `trustServerCertificate` as you are effectively ignoring the certificate completely, and anyone could just MITM your connection without you knowing. The comment should have read `// Change to 'false' if you want to validate the certificate and get a properly secure connection`